# Python summing elements of one dict if the have a similar key(tuple)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one single dictionary looking like this:

```
{('20144', 'Wirtschaftskammer Österreich Fachverband der Telekommunikations- und Rundfunkunternehmungen', 'Bezirksrundschau Oberösterreich', '4'): 12321.88, ('20143', 'Wirtschaftskammer Niederösterreich Fachgruppe Unternehmensberatung und Informationstechnologie NÖ', 'trend', '31'): 5700.53, ('20144', 'Wirtschaftskammer Tirol - Sparte Gewerbe und Handwerk Innung der Lebensmittelgewerbe', 'ORF Radio Tirol', '4'): 5861.56, ('20144', 'Bundesministerium für Land- und Forstwirtschaft Umwelt und Wasserwirtschaft', 'Weekend Magazin', '2'): 17355.1, ('20144', 'Bundesministerium für Land- und Forstwirtschaft Umwelt und Wasserwirtschaft', 'Woman', '2'): 12911.5, ('20144', 'Bundesministerium für Wissenschaft Forschung und Wirtschaft', 'Die Presse', '31'): 30965.4, ('20143', 'Bundesministerium für Europa Integration und Äußeres', 'Kronen Zeitung', '4'): 52490.46,.......)}
```

I want to to sum all the values where the key has the same number in front (for example `20144`) and the same number at the end (`2` or `31` for example).

I thought about a dict comprehension but I am struggling with comparing the keys I need. How can I easily compare them?

Comment: In the instance where the first number is `20144`, but the last number is `2` or `31`, would that go into the same summation or two different summations?

Comment: It would be two different summations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
trimmed={}
for k,v in data.items(): 
    trimmed.setdefault((k[0],k[-1]),[]).append(v)

{k:sum(v) for k,v in trimmed.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{('20144', '4'): 18183.44, ('20144', '31'): 30965.4, ('20143', '31'): 5700.53, ('20144', '2'): 30266.6, ('20143', '4'): 52490.46}
```

Given your example, this is what `trimmed` looks like after the `for` loop:

```
{('20144', '4'): [12321.88, 5861.56], ('20144', '31'): [30965.4], ('20143', '4'): [52490.46], ('20144', '2'): [12911.5, 17355.1], ('20143', '31'): [5700.53]}
```

**Explanation:**

The `for` loop is looping through your data keys (`k`) and key values (`v`) in your sample data. If the key `(k[0],k[-1])` (ie the first and last values in your key tuples--`('20144','4'):` for instance) does not exist in the new dictionary `trimmed` then a blank list is created and the value (`v`) is appended. If the key does exist then the value is simply appended.

After the `trimmed` dictionary is completed then a simple dictionary comprehension sums all these lists.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments you can also use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from `collections` if performance is an issue:

```
from collections import defaultdict

trimmed=defaultdict(float)
for k,v in data.items(): 
    trimmed[(k[0],k[-1])]+=v
```

And here the values are stored in `trimmed`. A newly initialized key in the `trimmed` defaultdict will be `0.0`. Then you can just add in place `v`.

Comment: use `defaultdict` instead of `setdefault`. It is usually significantly faster and eminently more readable. And instead of defaulting to a list, you can default to zero and sum.

Comment: Thanks for the explination and the solution! :-) I perfectly understood how this works!

Answer (score 1):

This can get you the results you are looking for:

```
dict = {('20144', 'Bundesministerium f\xc3\xbcr Land- und Forstwirtschaft Umwelt und Wasserwirtschaft', 'Woman', '2'): 12911.5, ('20144', 'Wirtschaftskammer Tirol - Sparte Gewerbe und Handwerk Innung der Lebensmittelgewerbe', 'ORF Radio Tirol', '4'): 5861.56, ('20144', 'Bundesministerium f\xc3\xbcr Land- und Forstwirtschaft Umwelt und Wasserwirtschaft', 'Weekend Magazin', '2'): 17355.1, ('20144', 'Bundesministerium f\xc3\xbcr Wissenschaft Forschung und Wirtschaft', 'Die Presse', '31'): 30965.4, ('20144', 'Wirtschaftskammer \xc3\x96sterreich Fachverband der Telekommunikations- und Rundfunkunternehmungen', 'Bezirksrundschau Ober\xc3\xb6sterreich', '4'): 12321.88, ('20143', 'Wirtschaftskammer Nieder\xc3\xb6sterreich Fachgruppe Unternehmensberatung und Informationstechnologie N\xc3\x96', 'trend', '31'): 5700.53, ('20143', 'Bundesministerium f\xc3\xbcr Europa Integration und \xc3\x84u\xc3\x9feres', 'Kronen Zeitung', '4'): 52490.46}
sum_by_key = {}
filter_obj = None
for key, value in dict.items():
  sum_key = (key[0], key[-1])
  if sum_key in sum_by_key:
    sum_by_key[sum_key] += value
  else:
    sum_by_key[sum_key] = value
```

The output:

```
{('20144', '2'): 30266.6, ('20143', '31'): 5700.53, ('20144', '31'): 30965.4, ('20144', '4'): 18183.44, ('20143', '4'): 52490.46}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`. See if the following code suits you (I used `d` as your dict).

**Edit: dict needed to be sorted**

```
fields = lambda k: (k[0], k[3])
for k, i in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=fields), key=fields):
    ...:     print(k, sum(d[v] for v in i))

('20143', '31') 5700.53
('20143', '4') 524.23
('20144', '2') 30266.6
('20144', '31') 30965.4
('20144', '4') 18183.44
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :-(
I am getting this error: KeyError: (('20144', 'Salzburg AG für Energie Verkehr und Telekommunikation', 'Bezirksblätter Salzburg', '2'), 27166.75)

Comment: `('20143', 'Bundesministerium für Europa Integration und Äußeres', 'Kronen Zeitung', '4'): 52490.46`.

Comment: @LMc: yup, I changed the values when deleting the dots at the end.

Comment: @matiasg nice, just want to point out that your code outputs the correct thing, but the output you have printed here is incorrect. See `('20143', '4') 524.23` and my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done in one pass, taking advantage of `defaultdict` from the standard library:

```
import collections
output_dict = collections.defaultdict(float)
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    output_dict[ (key[0], key[-1]) ] += value


# show the output
print('\n'.join('%r: %r' % (key,value) for key, value in output_dict.items()))
```

Prints as follows:

```
('20144', '2'): 30266.6
('20143', '31'): 5700.53
('20144', '31'): 30965.4
('20144', '4'): 18183.44
('20143', '4'): 52490.46
```